# Customizing SugarCRM 6.5 theme

Tags: sugarcrm

I am new to SugarCRM 6.5 CE.
I have been trying to make custom theme by copying the already available themes and changing the name of folder.
The theme is now available in the drop down but any changes I am making to its CSS is not taking place.
Thanks in advance.
Here is my themedef file

```
  $themedef = array(
    'name'  => "Test",
    'description' => "Default theme from Sugar 5",
    'version' => array(
        'regex_matches' => array('6\.*.*'),
        ),
    'group_tabs' => true,
    'parentTheme' => "Test",
    );
```

Comment: Please post some of your code that highlights the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the parent theme like this:

'parentTheme' => "Sugar5", // this is the standard theme you want to overwrite.

Comment: I'm on the same task right now. As it seems the overwriting doesn't work as it should. You have to include all the images from the original sugar5 theme as it seems. Also the theme setting of the User could interfere with the default.